# How to write an SQL query to find out which logins have been granted which rights in Sql Server 2005?

Tags: sql, database

I'm responsible for some test database servers.  Historically, too many other poeple have access to them.  They run on `SQL Server 2005`.

I've been writing queries and wrapping them in scripts so I can run a regular audit of rights.  Finding out which users had Administrator rights on the server itself was fine, as was finding out who had the `sysadmin` role on their login - it was a single line query for the latter.

But how to find out which logins have a User Mapping to a particular (or any) database?

I can find the `sys.database_principals` and `sys.server_principals` tables.  I have located the `sys.databases table`.  I haven't worked out how to find out which users have rights on a database, and if so, what.

Every Google search brings up people manually using the User Mapping pane of the Login dialog, rather than using a query to do so. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do this.  I ended up finding reference to a sproc in the MSDN docs.  I pulled this from the sproc and wrapped it in a loop of all the databases known to the instance.

```
select DbRole = g.name, MemberName = u.name
  from @NAME.sys.database_principals u, @NAME.sys.database_principals g, @NAME.sys.database_role_members m
  where   g.principal_id = m.role_principal_id
    and u.principal_id = m.member_principal_id
    and g.name in (''db_ddladmin'', ''db_owner'', ''db_securityadmin'') 
    and u.name not in (''dbo'')
  order by 1, 2
```

This then reports the users that have DBO who perhaps shouldn't.  I've already revoked some admin access from some users that they didn't need.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Check out this msdn reference article on [Has_Perms_By_Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx).  I think you're really interested in examples D, F and G

---

Another idea... I fired up SQL profiler and clicked on the ObjectExplorer->Security->Users.  This resulted in (approx) the following query being issued.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  sys.database_principals AS u
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_permissions AS dp
  ON dp.grantee_principal_id = u.principal_id and dp.type = N'CO'
WHERE (u.type in ('U', 'S', 'G', 'C', 'K'))
ORDER BY [Name] ASC
```

Comment: David, I think you're on the money.  I'll need to test it out when I get to work tomorrow. Will update this question.  Thank you so much!

Comment: +1 Thanks David Worked Great , changed Select * to Name and it does every thing i needed :D

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Master.dbo.syslogins l inner join sys.sysusers u on l.sid = u.sid
```

This will get you what users are mapped to which logins within a single database.